# PHP: for loop $i value turns zero if the number is greater

Tags: php

I want to turn the $i variable value to start counting from 1 if the given value is greater than 10:
here is what i am trying to achieve

```
<?php
   $givenValue = 15; //number of x value
    for ($i = 1; $i < $givenValue; $i++) {

        if ($givenValue > 10){
           $i = 1;
        }

        echo $i."<br>";   

    }

?>
```

This is how i want my result to look like 

     output: 1

     output: 2

     output: 3

     output: 4

     output: 5

     output: 6

     output: 7

     output: 8

     output: 9

     output: 10

     output: 1

     output: 2

     output: 3

     output: 4

     output: 5

in for loop body

Any help is welcome

Comment: You create an infinite loop. Usually PHP interpreters stop when they notice it.

Comment: You're also missing all of the semi-colons you need for this to compile.

Comment: The Modulo operator should get you there. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Comment: Oh thanks let me correct that;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resenting the counter, I would expect the behaviour you have.  To do what you want add another counter to the mix

```
 $j=1;
 $givenValue = 15; //number of x value
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $givenValue; $i++) {

    if ($j > 10){
       $j = 1;
    }

    echo $j."\n";
    ++$j;   
 }
```

You also had several missing `;`

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you want to end on 5 you have to do 16 as the `$givenValue` or change it to `<=` less than or equal

See it [here live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf2017cc5ee9f28c8c5868e72fc80e11282c7c0c)

See what I have now, the `$i` variable counts to the `$givenValue` then the `$j` variable counts along side it, but with a range of 1-10 ( resets to 1 after 10 )

Comment: thanks for the help i just change my for ($i = 1; $i <= $givenValue; $i++) to for ($i = 0; $i <= $givenValue; $i++)  and its works like charm

Comment: That will count to six.  Don't you mean `for ($i = 0; $i < $givenValue; $i++)`  For me it makes more sense to keep `$i` at the same value as`$j`, well until it hits 10.   But it's six 1 half dozen

Answer (score 4):

You can use modulo calculation to get the result you want.
I also changed your if from `$givenvalue` to `$i` as `$givenvalue` will "always" be 10+.

```
$givenValue = 15; //number of x value
for ($i = 1; $i <= $givenValue; $i++) {

    if ($i > 10){
       Echo $i%10 . "\n";
    }else{

       echo $i . "\n";
    }

}
```

https://3v4l.org/5afc5

---

Another option, if that is possible for you, is to start at zero and only use modulo calculation and add one to it to get the same result.
This also means I need to stop the loop at `<$givenvalue` as your original code shows.

```
$givenValue = 15; //number of x value
for ($i = 0; $i < $givenValue; $i++) {
    Echo $i%10+1 . "\n";     
}
```

https://3v4l.org/r0sgA

---

A method that uses less looping is to add 10 to the loop on each iteration and create the values using range().
Then add them to the array with array_merge, and output with implode.

```
$givenValue = 47; //number of x value
$breakpoint = 10;
$arr=[];
For($i = $breakpoint; $i< $givenValue;){
    // Add new values from 1-$breakpoint in array
    $arr = array_merge($arr, range(1,$breakpoint));
    $i +=$breakpoint;
}
// Loop will exit before all values been collected
// Add the rest of the values
$arr = array_merge($arr, range(1,$givenValue-($i-10)));
// Echo the values in array
Echo implode("\n", $arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/jGsO4

Comment: modulus has a glitch it  add extra one to the result which is not proper

Comment: @Michael where? Look at the links in my answer, 1-10,1-5 as you requested.

Comment: @Michael can you answer my question? What do you mean with "glitch" and "add extra one"?

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be written like this:

```
<?php 
$givenValue = 15; //number of x value 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $givenValue; $i++) 
{ 
    if ($i > 10)
    { 
        $i = 1; 
        $givenValue-=10;
    } 
    echo "output: $i\n"; 
} 
?>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed34d8dcd12a9a5a866b73338ad1209f55298519

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to vote on yours, then when I try taking the + away it just does - instead of 0.  So guess you get a + too.  Sorry man....  But after checking it, it's as good an answer as any... cheers.  As a side note I never downvote, only upvote, but I meant to do it on @Andreas answer, like I said.

Comment: The answer is cool the but modulus did not fit it best. Because the number start start counting from 0 instead of 1

Comment: If you read the OP's comment in mine, they  decided `0` was better then `<=`.  So I look at that like a minor detail.  Inconsequential, but yours is a good answer so you deserved the upvote regardless, cheers..

Comment: Nah, it's okay. Anyway, the modulus one (2nd) is the best one. It doesn't start from 0.